# Computing issue in writing program

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a quick test program that would add two number inclusively, let say one integer is 2 and the other is 7, I want it to compute like this (2+3+4+5+6+7=27). Can't wrap my head around it.

Here is what I have

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int lo=2;
        int hi=7;

        int result=0;

        for(int i=lo;i<=hi;i++)
            result=i+i;

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. I think you mean

```
result = result + i;
```

This basically means take the current value of `result`, add `i` to it, and then make `result` equal to that sum. This has the overall effect of adding `i` to `result`.

There's also a short-hand for `_something_ = _something_ + _otherThing_`, which in this case would look like:

```
result += i;
```

Comment: You are my hero, I didnt see that

Comment: @Tuan: No problem. Glad to have helped!

Comment: @Tuan - `result += i` is also correct.  And a lot of people would say it looks nicer.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, u guys are genuises

Comment: @Stephen: Thanks, meant to add that as a note.

Answer (score 0):

Use some math:

> Sn = n/2 * (A1 + An),

where Sn is the sum of arithmetic progression of n elements with A1 as first element and An as last. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression).

Comment: Yes I could use that but we were suppose to write it with a for loop